# Perl sub doesn't want to work with passed objects as parameters

Tags: perl, oop, date

I pass two `Date::Manip::Date` objects, perfectly valid dates to my sub:

```
sub get_duration {
        my $duration;
        my @val;

        my $from = $_[0]->new_date();
        my $to = $_[1]->new_date();
    #   $from->parse("2012-03-06");
    #   $to->parse("2012-03-07");

        print $from . " ".$to. "<-- <br />";

        my @f = $from->value();
        if ($f[0] == 2012) {
            $from->config("ConfigFile",$HOLIDAYS_2012);
        } elsif ($f[0] == 2013) {
            $from->config("ConfigFile",$HOLIDAYS_2013);
        } elsif ($f[0] == 2014) {
            $from->config("ConfigFile",$HOLIDAYS_2014);
        } elsif ($f[0] == 2015) {
            $from->config("ConfigFile",$HOLIDAYS_2015);
        }
        my @t = $to->value();
        if ($t[0] == 2012) {
            $to->config("ConfigFile",$HOLIDAYS_2012);
        } elsif ($t[0] == 2013) {
            $to->config("ConfigFile",$HOLIDAYS_2013);
        } elsif ($t[0] == 2014) {
            $to->config("ConfigFile",$HOLIDAYS_2014);
        } elsif ($t[0] == 2015) {
            $to->config("ConfigFile",$HOLIDAYS_2015);
        }

        print "from " . @f ." to ". @t."<br>";

        my $delta = $from->calc($to, "business");
        print $from->calc($to, "business") . " <-";

        @val = $delta->value();

        if ($to->is_business_day()) {
            $duration = $val[3]+1;
        } else {
            $duration = $val[3];
        }

        return $duration;
    }
```

I get the output

```
Date::Manip::Date=HASH(0xacdf7a0) Date::Manip::Date=HASH(0xacdfb50)<-- 
from 0 to 0
<-
Software error:

Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at '@val = $delta->value();'
```

That is the two dates are passed all right, I got NO errors when it tries to set their config files, Regardless, the value arrays `@t` and `@f` are empty and it breaks down as soon as I try to get the delta.

However if I uncomment the two lines

```
   $from->parse("2012-03-06");
   $to->parse("2012-03-07");
```

(hence ignoring the parameters)
It works just fine as intended.

There's something I'm missing about passing objects in Perl I suspect?

Firstly 
`&get_overlap_duration($saved[$i][5], $saved[$i][6], $saved[$i][7], $saved[$i][8])`
Is called 
I've printed the @saved values and they're correct, they're strings:
`2012-03-06, 2012-03-08, 2012-03-05, 2012-03-07`

Then inside `get_overlap_duration` those strings are

```
my $from1 = new Date::Manip::Date;
my $to1 = new Date::Manip::Date;
my $from2 = new Date::Manip::Date;
my $to2 = new Date::Manip::Date;

$from1->parse($_[0]);
$to1->parse($_[1]);
$from2->parse($_[2]);
$to2->parse($_[3]);
```

Then there's there is a call for `get_duration` for instance `$duration = get_duration($from2, $to1);`

I've checked the server error log there were no complaints apart from the software error displayed in the browser.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: Yes double checked now and added explanation

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that on the following line:

```
        my $delta = $from->calc($to, "business");
```

It's not returning a valid object.  Which likely means that something in the calc() function is failing.  Since "business" is not a valid date.  And if you read the Date::Manip::Calc man page, the `mode` parameter is only legal when you pass in two date objects before that and you've only passed one.

Comment: Cant be that I use similar code in a different sub to calculate "used" business days between 2 dates $`delta = $date_from->calc($date_to, "business");`
`@val = $delta->value();`
`if ($date_to->is_business_day()) {
$period += $val[3]` etc

Comment: Either way in the documentation I can't see where 2 date objects are passed, only $subtract which I don't need which is also optional as "business" is.

Comment: The get_duration sub works as intended if I pass the dates as simple strings and inside I change it at the start like this:
`my $from = new Date::Manip::Date;`
 `my $to = new Date::Manip::Date;`
 
 `$from->parse($_[0]);`
 `$to->parse($_[1]);`

Comment: It might be worth running your script in the perl debugger (run it with `perl -d`) because the problem is still as stated: the calc function isn't returning what you want it to return (a valid object reference).  If you run it the debugger you can step into the calc() function and see where it's returning from and why it's failing based on your inputs.